# How to add custom emojis into an Embedded message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

##### What I've done:

I have attempted to add custom emojis inside my embed. However, this hasn't succeeded. Perhaps I'm using outdated code? I'm not sure what exactly is causing this to not work. I'm not getting any feedback from the console and all my other commands work.

```
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(865698553737117696)
    firework = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, name="firework")
    phone = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, name= "socials")
    react = discord.Embed(title = 'Reaction Roles:',description = 'Below are a range of reaction roles that allows you to be pinged when we announce something exciting:\n',colour = 0xE23D6E)

    react.set_author(name='Disney Dreams', icon_url= 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/809937571793993730/866327668970881034/logogoosggs.png')
    react.add_field(name='**Shows**', value=f'{firework}' + ': Allows you to get pinged when we make an announcement relating to shows here at Disney Dreams', inline= False)
    react.add_field(name='**Social Media**',
    value=f'{phone}' + ': Allows you to get pinged when we make a post on one of our social media pages', inline=False)

    reactions = await channel.send(embed=react)

    await reactions.add_reaction(':firework:')
    await reactions.add_reaction(':socials:')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the way you use to get the emojis is outdated. To do this is very simple.

```py
<a:emojiname:emojiid>
```

You can replace `emojiname` with the emoji's name and `emojiid` with the emoji ID. You can simply get `<a:emojiname:emojiid>` easily by typing in a discord channel `\emoji` and the message will format it into what you need. Of course repace the `emoji` in `\emoji` with the actual emoji.

**Only use `<a:emojiname:emojiid>` for animated emojis**

**To use for normal emojis or static emojis, use `<:emojiname:emojiid>`**